# angularjs 1.3 javascript animation works on ng-repeat but not ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to emulate some standard js code (with jQuery) in angularJS, for practice mostly, but I am pleased with how much simpler the angularJS code is.

However, I have a problem with an animation:

```
angular.module('app').animation('.slideDown', function() {
    return {
        enter: function (element, done) {
            jQuery(element).slideDown(2500);
        }
    }
});
```

When I apply this to an ng-repeat-start the animation works just fine and the element reveals by sliding into view from the top:

```
    <div class="slideDown" data-ng-repeat-start="c in vm.things" style="display: none;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            [content...]
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, when I apply it to an ng-if (within the ng-repeat-end) the element doesn't reveal itself at all.  If I take out the "display: none;" the element appears on the page (with no presentational flare):

```
    <div data-ng-repeat-end>
        <div class="slideDown" data-ng-if="($index+1)%6==0" style="display: none;">
            [content...]
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please can someone tell me why the angularJS javascript animation works in the ng-repeat-start, but not on the ng-if?

btw - inline style is used here simply to demonstrate the problem; I don't use inline styles in dev, let alone production!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default child elements cannot be animated until the parent's animation has completed. You can however use the attribute `ng-animate-children` on a parent container element to override this.

For example:

```
<body ng-controller="MyController" ng-animate-children>
  <div class="slideDown" data-ng-repeat-start="c in vm.things" style="display: none;">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      [Fizz...]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-ng-repeat-end>
    <div class="slideDown" data-ng-if="($index+1)%3==0" style="display: none;">
      [Buzz...]
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/vsvMdr3DZJqQRpG8SPzx?p=preview